# jPlayer Play only a section of the sound

Tags: jquery, html5-audio, jplayer

I couldn't find an answer to this question. I'm trying this:

```
$("#klikk").click(function() {
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play", 2).delay(2000).jPlayer("pause", 0);
  });
```

But not working. 
Whats happening: simply don't stop the sound. W/O the delay it's stopping immidiately. 
So what I need: if I click on the link, play the section from 2 to 4 seconds.

Thansk for help!

Comment: how to limit 30 second only play the song

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$("#klikk").click(function() {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play", 2); 
});

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) { 
    if(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime > 4) { 
        $(this).jPlayer("pause"); 
    } 
});
```

Adapted from this [post](http://groups.google.com/group/jplayer/browse_thread/thread/c92f09c0db2ca580?fwc=1).

Good luck!